# Calculating confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am curious as to why I am getting two different 95% confident intervals in R, given a mean of $0.008$, an SD of $0.1035697$ and $n = 39$ (normal distributed). When I use the code:

```
a <- mean(m)

n <- 39

s <- sd(m)

error <- s/sqrt(n)

a + error 

a - error
```

I get a 95% confidence interval $(-0.02450488, 0.04050488)$ using this method, but when I just use t.test(m) I get $(-0.02557342,0.04157342)$. Why is that?

Comment: BTW the formula for CI shouldn't it be $[a - 2*error , a + 2*error]$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your manual approach, you did not use $\left[a-\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}},a+\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$ for your confidence interval but instead something like $\left[a-1.96\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}},a+1.96\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$ where the $1.96$ can be found in R with `qnorm(0.975)`

Since you are estimating the standard deviation from the observations, you would do better to use a Student $t$-distribution with $39-1=38$ degrees of freedom and consider `qt(0.975,n-1)` which is $2.024394$.  That will get you closer to the results from `t.test()`

Comment: (+1) Is there a typo here: *In your manual approach, you **did not** use...*? Shouldn't it be something like *you **should not** use...*? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @dariober If the OP's formulae as originally stated had been applied you would get something like $(-0.008584425,0.02458442)$ rather than the claimed *"I get a $95\%$ confidence interval $(-0.02450488, 0.04050488)$ using this method"*,  while multiplying the estimated standard error by $1.96$ fixes this anomaly.

Comment: Oh I get it now... Thanks for clarifying!